# Transformation to a uniformly rotating frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm midway through a problem at the beginning of a GR course, my question is simply this:

If
$$
x=x'\cos\Omega t-y'\sin\Omega t
$$
where $x'$ and $y'$ indicate the rotated frame of reference. What does that make $dx^2$?

I need this so I can make substitutions into the equation:
$$
ds^2=c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2
$$

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53769/226902 ("Metric coefficients in rotating coordinates"), see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427492/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/651120/226902. Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613281/226902

Answer (score 1):

$$ dx = \cos (\Omega t) dx' -x' \Omega \sin (\Omega t) dt - \sin (\Omega t) dy' -y' \Omega \cos (\Omega t) dt$$

It's basically just the product rule and the chain rule.