# Derivation of coordinate transform for rotating frame of reference in relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I was wondering what is the relativistic coordinate transform between an rotating frame of reference and an inertial one.
I have seen the following formula
$$t=t'$$
$$x=x' \cos \omega t' - y' \sin \omega t'$$
$$y=x' \sin \omega t' + y' \cos \omega t'$$
$$z=z'$$

for $(t,x,y,z)$ being the coordinates of an inertial frame of reference and $(t',x',y',z')$ the coordinates of a rotating one. Is this correct? If yes
can you give me a hint on how to derive this, perhaps a way to visualize it.

Comment: It's the same coordinate transformation  that is used non-relativistic mechanics. SR pr GR makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. To get it, you use the formula for a rotation by $\theta$ around the origin of the $x'$-$y'$ plane,

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y'
\end{array} \right),
$$
and combine it with the formula for constant rotation
$$
\theta = \omega t,
$$
with $\omega$ the angular velocity.
Hopefully this makes the intuition clear: one coordinate system $(x,y)$ is rotated relative to the other one $(x',y')$ by an angle $\theta$, and $\theta$ is rotating with constant angular velocity.

Indeed, as pointed out in a comment, since we're only performing a spatial rotation and not a Lorentz boost, this formula applies in ordinary, non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics just as well as special relativity.